# How to style Google Maps as treasure map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

One of Google 1 April jokes related to Google Maps, in which they restyled Google Maps into a huge treasure map.

How can I style my (custom) Google Map as treasure map?

Comment: google map wizard: http://googlemaps.github.io/js-samples/styledmaps/wizard/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think ***there is no Google's treasure map API available***.  But customizing the background image of map is possible.

1. [**Styled Maps**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling): Styled maps allow you to customize the presentation of the standard Google base maps, changing the visual display of such elements as roads, parks, and built-up areas.
2. [**Image Map Types**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes?hl=pl#ImageMapTypes): Map types that consist of tiles made up of single image files.  Check this [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image?hl=pl).

Get an image similar to Google treasure maps and add it as mentioned in the above link and learn to add custom projection.

- [**Custom map projections**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes?hl=pl#Projections): a projection can be defined as a
  mapping of latitude/longitude values into coordinates on the
  projection's map.  Get the code from [**here**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-projection-simple?hl=pl).

Hope you understand.